# find common rows based on specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, I would like to find the common rows based on a specific columns.

```
packing_id  col1  col2  col3 col4
1            1.0  2.0
2            2.0  2.0
3            1.0  1.0
4            3.0  3.0
.             .    .
.             .    .
```

I would like to find the rows where the `col1` and `col2` values are the same.
I tried
`np.where(df.col1==df.col2)` but it is not the right approach. I would appreciate your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 1):

I think your soluton is good, only add 2 parameters to `np.where`:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df.col1==df.col2, 'same', 'no same')
```

If need filter them:

```
df1 = df[df.col1==df.col2]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be work. Thanks

```
df[df.col1==df.col2]
```